# chrome/safari loses rounded corners during a jQuery slide transition

Tags: jquery, slider, rounded-corners, css3pie

I am using the jquery script shown here - http://jqueryfordesigners.com/automatic-infinite-carousel/.

I have applied my own images as rounded png's into the slider on my site - `http://67.225.219.80/`

All is well in firefox and IE9 using border-radius. You can see the rounded corners are maintained even with the slider is sliding during auto mode and even when the slider is controlled by the arrows.

However in chrome/safari, the rounded corners disappear during the transition.

In addition to giving the outer div wrapper rounded corners (border-radius, -webkit-border-radius, etc.), I have also tried applying rounded corners to the nested ul, li, a, and img elements to see if it would work, still no solution.

I am also using css3pie, after some testing I've concluded that this is not the cause of the problem occuring in chrome/safari.

Anyone have any experience with this or guide me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be a webkit bug, it seems to be fixed in the current webkit (on mac)

Comment: Maybe this bug? https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67950

Comment: @biziclop i am using a mac. what is the current webkit that you are referring too?

Comment: I tried on OSX10.5, WebKit Version 5.0.6 (5533.22.3, r97225).
On plain Safari (Version 5.0.6 (5533.22.3)) the bug appears. If this effect is very important, you can try webkit's css-mask with a manually created SVG mask: http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

Comment: @biziclop you are correct, thank you for the reference link. well if its a bug its a bug. i will try the css mask. i think it will work. thanks! appreciate your help.