# Overflow: hidden with border radius not working on Safari

Tags: html, css

I have to make a button with a `::before` hidden which shows on `:hover`. This animation is working great on Chrome, IE and Firefox, but i have a weird issue on **Safari.**

Overflow:hidden is working but without the border radius.

You should run the fiddle in safari to see this issue.

Thanks !

```css
.btn{
  border-radius: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.8rem 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.btn-primary{
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.btn-primary::before{
  background-color: deeppink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1.4, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.9,1);
  width: 20%;
}

.btn-primary:hover::before{
  transform: scale3d(1, 5, 1);
  width: 110%;
  left: -2%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.btn-primary span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span>Button primary</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried this in Safari on a Mac or Windows system? My experience with safari for windows is that it is exceptionally buggy.

Comment: I tried this on a Mac

Comment: Do you get the same result when adding -webkit- tags to your css like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pec8ownx/)?

Comment: I'm using autoprefixer in my project so it automatically add every -webkit tags I need

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The accepted answer works, but indeed it removes the box shadow. A comment I saw in this [github post](https://gist.github.com/ayamflow/b602ab436ac9f05660d9c15190f4fd7b) says that it can be also fixed by creating a new stacking context (kind of moving an element into a new painting layer). That can be achieved with a small hack like

```
transform: translateZ(0)
```

In my case, both `overflow` and `box-shadow` are working with this solution.

UPD: just like [@JadHaidar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5483329) suggested in the comments `isolation` is a property specifically for working with the stacking context:

```
isolation: isolate;
```

Comment: One other way to create a new stacking context is by using `isolation: isolate;` Not supported by IE but is technically more correct.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation

Comment: Which element are you adding this style to?

Comment: `isolation: isolate;` was and fast and easy fix for me.

Comment: Apply isolation: isolate; to the element with overflow:hidden property.

Comment: `isolation: isolate;` fixed my similar issue - very interesting! Could someone explain or provide some docs related to stacking order and how this fixes the issue? I'd love to know

Answer (score 57):

So I found a little hack to fix this issue on https://gist.github.com/ayamflow/b602ab436ac9f05660d9c15190f4fd7b

Just add this line to your element with overflow :

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
```

Let me know if someone find another solution :)

```css
.btn{

  /* Add this line */
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);

  border-radius: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.8rem 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.btn-primary{
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.btn-primary::before{
  background-color: deeppink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1.4, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.9,1);
  width: 20%;
}

.btn-primary:hover::before{
  transform: scale3d(1, 5, 1);
  width: 110%;
  left: -2%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.btn-primary span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span>Button primary</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, thanks! Only pitfall was, that I had to move my box-shadow to another div, but I can live with that ;)

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Comment: thanks. I'm very confused/curious why this fixes the issue

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This overflow bug in iOS was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 24):

`will-change: transform;` on element with `overflow: hidden;` solved issue for me

Comment: careful tho, the will-change property is not supported by IE at all and Edge earlier versions.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I believe the crux of all these answers is they bump the div into a new layer (i.e. `transform: translateZ(0)`) and for some reason that achieves the desired effect on Safari

Answer (score 22):

This is caused by one of several unresolved bugs in WebKit, the rendering engine used by Safari:

- [Border-radius clip of non-stacking composited descendant doesn't work](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140535)
- [overflow: hidden + border radius does not work when transform is added to child](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98538)

As Simon Fraser writes in the second link:

> You can work around it in recent builds by making the element with overflow:hidden into a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) (e.g. position:relative, z-index:0).

This is probably the simplest solution since, unlike some of the other answers here, it does not unnecessarily [introduce render layers](https://dassur.ma/things/forcing-layers/).

Answer (score 14):

For me, adding a high `z-index` setting to the item with the `border-radius`, was enough to fix the problem.

Comment: This helped me too! Never thought of it. Thanks!

Comment: I found that setting `z-index: 0` is enough, and shouldn't have consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these on your parent component:

```
clip-path: inset(0 0 round 50%);
clip-path: inset(0 0 round 3rem);
clip-path: inset(0 0 round 20px);
```

Clip-path is considered partially supported nowadays, but that applies to full specification, which has a lot of functionality.
Specifically **inset** should be [supported widely](https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn{
  border-radius: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: arial;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.8rem 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.btn-primary{
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.btn-primary::before{
  background-color: deeppink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1.4, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.9,1);
  width: 20%;
}

.btn-primary:hover::before{
  transform: scale3d(1, 5, 1);
  width: 110%;
  left: -2%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.btn-primary span{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span>Button primary</span>
</a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).